# chart.js how add euro symbol on each node

Tags: chart.js

i'm using chart.js 3.0
i want to add the euro sybol on each y-axis value.
with this code:

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            ticks: {
                // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                    return '$' + value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

i add the dollar symbol on each y-axis value, I want to show the euro symbol (€), but if i use this code:

```
callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                    return '€' + value;
                }
```

i get a bad result, i get the symbol ? instead of the € symbol
how i can fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reproducable since it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/h1rso9n4/

Comment: i found the problem but not the solution. 
if I call the file chartjs.html the euro symbol appears correctly

if I call the file chartjs.php, the euro symbol does not appear, but a question mark appears.

I work on a site in php so I need the file to be chartjs.php - here there is the link to my code: https://www.b2m.it/andrea/chartjs.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the Euro symbol, try to use its Unicode as follows.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
      ticks: {
        callback: v => v + '\u20AC'
      }
    }
}
```